# Wordpress - Hook don't fire until update post manually from backend

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I'm trying to run a function that prints watermark on image when a new post is creates from a plugin that generates a new post and associates an uploaded photo as featured image.

Function works well only if i manually update/create posts from back-end and not working when posts is create from front-end.

here my code on functions.php:

```
// stampa watermark

function stampa_watermark () {
  $slug = 'foto';
  $post_id = get_the_ID();
  $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
  $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id, 'full' );
  $image_size = 'full';
  $filepath = get_attached_file( $attachment_id );
  $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();



  if ( $slug != $post_type ) {
        return;
    }
  else {
    $IW = new Image_Watermark;
    $IW->do_watermark( $attachment_id, $filepath, $image_size, $upload_dir );

    }
}

add_action( 'updated_postmeta', 'stampa_watermark' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'stampa_watermark' );

// fine
```

Comment: Have you written the code that creates posts on the front-end?

Comment: No, is bit complex, posts are creates by appcamera plugin, it's a part of apppresser plugin. I have found some info to hook inside that plugin but if i change 'save_post' or 'updated_postmeta' with the suggested action the result don't change. Here are some info: http://docs.apppresser.com/article/126-appcamera they suggest to use: 'appp_after_process_uploads' but didn't fires.

Comment: If the plugin does not provide an appropriate hook, you can alternatively try to use `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` or `post_thumbnail_html` or to process the image before it's displayed.

Comment: @TheFallen Thanks for the reply but if i use `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` or `post_thumbnail_html ` upload doesn't works fine. I have found a walk around including `do_watermark()` directly where photos are upload without any callback functions or actions. Now watermark is fine, but I have one more issue: I need to print watermark not only on full size's image but on all image thumbnails, I asked to watermark's plugin author for some help, the problem is to extract file path of all image thumbnails and pass them to `do_watermark()` function as `$filepath` variable.